# How can I secure a door latch blocker without drilling?

Tags: doors, latches

I have a door latch cover that looks like this:

[image]

Its installed in a common area so I cannot drill any holes. Right now its attached to the door with an elastic band as shown in the photo but they keep stretching out so I constantly have to replace them. What could I use instead of an elastic band to make this more or less permanent? First thing that comes to mind is to use a metal wire but how do I connect the two free ends after cutting out a big enough piece?

Many years ago I've seen a small metal connector used on a clothesline where you put two ends of the cable inside and then used the screw to make the rope tight, but I can't remember what it was called and can't find it in Google. Something like this would be perfect for my purposes.

Comment: look under the cover ... do you see any screws?

Comment: @jsotola yes but the latch cover isn't big enough for me to use the existing holes in the metal part of the latch. If this was my own door I'd just make a hole on the wooden sides and call it a day but sadly that's not an option

Comment: Zip ties.  Small ones

Comment: @Kris thank you! I *knew* I'm missing a very simple solution here, just couldn't figure out what. This should work perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Use cable ties instead of the elastic bands.

[image]

Comment: If the cable ties are too short, you can tie them together.  If you want to trim off excess, be sure to sand down any sharp corners, or tape them over; they will be quite sharp.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use wire bend both ends of the wire round the anchor tab of the blocker.

I worry that wire might mar the door handle, something soft like string or parachute cord might be a better choice. You may need an assistant to help you tie the knot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found that simply putting a flat metal plate over the strike plate offered free access. This is a more permanent solution as if you want the door to lock our stay closed occasionally you would have to remove the metal plate to accomplish normal use.

Comment: How did you secure the metal plate to the door?